# How can I have a default value in a non required django form field?

Tags: django-forms

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   ...
   my_field = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

By default, my_field will have None, if it wasn't completed. How can I make it have a default value? Is there any way I wouldn't have to use `initial`? I don't want it displaying the default value inside the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull the value from the form, set it to the default if it has no value.

```
my_value = myform.cleaned_data['my_field'] or SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE
```